# How to use date variable in sql developer's "Enter Binds" dialog?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run a query from sql developer and query has variables (`:var`). I am having problem with the date variables.

I used all the possible combinations to format date using `to_date()` function. 
Every time getting below exception:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Sorry can't post image here

Comment: If you don't show us some code, we can't help....

Comment: okay so my query will be something like this

select first_name, last_name, dob, org from emp
where dob > :highDate;

when you run this query in sql developer you will see the "Enter Binds" pop to enter the value for variable :highDate.

Comment: and what value are you giving in `:highDate`?

Comment: Also, what is the datatype of DOB?  DATE?  Finally, what do you have NLS_DATE_FORMAT set to?

Comment: yes dob has date datatype  and the value i am passing is to_date('20-JAN-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')

Comment: As i have mentioned I have tried all the possible combination of date format like dd-MON-yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd..etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try changing your query to be:

```
select first_name,
       last_name,
       dob,
       org
  from emp
 where dob > to_date(:highDate,'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

then when prompted, enter `'20-JAN-2010'`.

Comment: thks Mark, is it mean we can't pass a function as variable?

Comment: as my query is too big make all these changes isn't there any otehr way

Comment: The issue is that it's a bind variable.  If you use a bind variable, it's a placeholder for a variable of a given type.  You can't pass an arbitrary string containing a function, no.  Consider that the query is parsed with the bind variable as a placeholder for a specific value of a given datatype.  If you can't re-write the query, then try setting the NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY' in the session, then executing the original query, and then entering '20-JAN-2010'.  In this case, Oracle should use the value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT and implicitly convert the string to a date.

Comment: Used alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy' command to set variable, but problem is I have some 15 tables in my query and they are using different date format!!

Comment: Then I see no choice but to resort to code changes.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak: I think you meant 'dd-mon-yyyy' in your query (to match the format of the value to enter into the prompt).

Comment: Corrected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Just copying the answer from Oracle Community forum:

> You should be able to enter dates which conform to your
>   `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting.
>
> e.g. If `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-YYYY`, you can enter
>   `24-jan-2011` for today's date.

Worked for me.

Comment: This is the *correct* answer, which works without modifying the query. Check the current `NLS` formats with  `select * from NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`. The same is valid for entering *timestamps* using `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`

Answer (score 2):

Try using a substitution variable.  For example:

```
select (&var - 1) from dual;
```

sql developer will ask you to enter a substitution variable value, which you can use a date value (such as sysdate or to_date('20140328', 'YYYYMMDD') or whatever date you wish).

Comment: I don't want to change the way.. as  i am copying my query from a property file and want to run that on sql developer as the query is too big to make the changes.

Comment: a simple search/replace ':' with a '&' should work.  Ctrl-F in SqlDeveloper will bring up the find/replace wizard

Comment: Substitution variables are very different from bind variables in many different ways, so this is not a valid solution. Substitution variables cause hard parse every time. Substitution variables allow SQL injection. Etc.

Comment: The poster just wanted to run a query in SQL Developer, this isn't exposing some big performance or security issue to the world.  This is a valid solution for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(:my_var, 'dd.mm.yyyy') my_date from dual;
```

and then enter something like `01.02.2017` (without `'`) as the value of `:my_var`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Probably because SQL plus doesn't have it.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2939749100346967872

Answer (score 0):

In the query provide the date in the below format

```
to_date(:var,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

and  while executing the query from sql developer, provide the value for var bind parameter as `29-DEC-1995`

note that you **should not** use quotes. Its implicitly done by SQL developer.
Happy Coding!